# Can I obtain the vertices of a square after rotating it with OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have the following declaration:

```
glBegin( GL_QUADS );
glColor3f(0.0f,0.7f,0.7f);
glVertex2f(x1,y1);
glVertex2f(x2,y2);
glVertex2f(x3,y3);
glVertex2f(x4,y4);
glEnd();
```

The question is: If I apply a rotation, let's say, of 20 degrees, how can I know where these vertices are then?
Because later I need to be able to click on the square and identify if the place where I am clicking is, indeed, inside the square or not.

Comment: Can't you just do the same transformation on your vertices on the CPU? In general, the problem of figuring out "what has been clicked on" is a tricky one, with different solutions in literature (ray-triangle intersection, draw everything using a different color which then you use for lookup, etc.). The problem of getting the vertices /after/ vertex transformations is also tricky; modern OpenGL allows you to do it via the [Transform Feedback](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transform_Feedback), but your code is OpenGL 1.x-ish so forget about that.

Comment: What do you mean by "do the same transformation on your vertices on the CPU"? @peppe

Comment: The problem here is that you're using very old style OpenGL (2 or earlier).  Modern OpenGL has transform feedback and other nice things.  To do transforms CPU-side you can use a library like glm if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I hope that nobody has used it in this millennium, there actually was a mechanism for getting transformed vertices in legacy OpenGL. It's called "feedback mode". Explaining it in detail is beyond the scope of an answer. But if you want to see how it worked, you can read up on it in the freely available online version of the [Red Book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html#name2).

The "click and identify" you talk about in your question is often called "picking" or "selection". There are numerous approaches to implement it, and the one to choose depends somewhat on your application. To give you a quick overview of some common approaches:

- Selection mode. This is almost as obsolete as feedback mode. It's as old, but I have a feeling that it was at least much more commonly used, so it might have better support. Still, I wouldn't recommend using it in new code. Again, if you want to learn about it anyway, the explanation can be found in the [Red Book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter13.html#name1).
- Modern OpenGL has a feature called Transform Feedback. While its primary purpose is different, it can be used to read back transformed vertices similar to legacy Feedback Mode.
- Draw the scene to an off screen buffer, with each object rendered in a different color. Then read back the color at the selection position, and map it to an object. This is a fairly elegant and efficient approach, and can be recommended if it works for your requirements.
- Perform the calculations in your own code on the CPU. Instead of transforming all objects, the much more efficient approach is normally to apply the inverse transformation to your pick point (which actually becomes a ray), and intersect it with the geometry.

Comment: I marked this as a solution since it actually provides ways to solve the problem. In the end, though, I didn't implement this functionality.